# How to close color box automatic with .js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, colorbox

How to close colorbox automatically, and stay on the page ... neither redirect to another page nor reload the page ... 
I have tried to use

parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
or
$.fn.colorbox.close();
or
$.colorbox.close();

but those were not work

Any idea? Thx u

Comment: if you execute $.colorbox.close() in the browser console then does the colorbox close ?

Comment: yes that's right, nothing happen

Comment: strange.. that works fine in the demo site.. ill let you know if i find the cause.

Comment: I am confused too, thx for tha attention

Answer (score 0):

Those all work depending on the situation. There isn't an alternative answer to how to close colorbox, you have something setup incorrectly.  Maybe you are loading colorbox twice or something.  There isn't enough information to determine why it isn't working from your post.  Consider adding a demo.